# Drupal Commerce Free Shipping For Some Products

Tags: 7, commerce

Drupal 7, Commerce

The Setup: A store with two products. They are a shippable item and a gift certificate.

The shippable item has a number of shipping options available.

Gift certificates have free shipping, and always go via first class mail.

I added a 'free shipping' shipping method. Unfortunately this always shows up in all checkouts, so someone could order a hundred shippable items and then select free shipping.

When I 'configure component' for the free shipping method, it lets me define a rule as to how this method is applied.

In this rule, I need to make a loop that goes through all line items, and if there are only products marked with a field called 'field_free_shipping', then show this method.

However.... Rules sucks. :-) I can make a loop, but then I can't ask it about the product node or the field.

What am I doing wrong? Any assistance appreciated.

I'll be adding a bounty to this question when it becomes eligible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In such a simple scenario, where you only have two products, I would just use the condition *Order contains a particular product* to look for the shippable product to enable the paid shipping service. I'd then use the same condition negated to enable the free shipping service.

Comment: Came back to answer my own question to see an authoritative answer. We have like 5 shipping methods (intl, expedited, etc), so I had to conditionalize all of them against the free shipping product. A bit of tedium, and will have to change in 5 places with each new product. Commerce could do this better but I don't know how. Thanks.

Comment: Ahh, if you have more shipping methods, then you can either manage them all individually like you have or else use a Rules component to define the condition set and just call the component from your various other Rules. That would let you maintain updates to the logic in a single place if, for example, you needed to add another free shipping product to the site.

Comment: not understanding a module doesn't mean it sucks. Yes, it's opaque, but once you wrap your hear around it (like drupal itself, there are almost no limits)

Comment: Of course, for a very limited number of products, you could just filter by the *particular product*. But how would you do this, when there are plenty of products, only some of which are shipped for free?