# Free Shipping for selected products in Drupal Commerce

Tags: commerce, rules

I'm trying to set up a rule to allow free shipping for selected products. I'd like to use a boolean field with a checkbox for free shipping. If the box is ticked the product should be excluded from any postage calculations during the checkout.

I'm using the commerce and commerce shipping module.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Drupal Commerce Free Shipping For Some Products](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/68000/drupal-commerce-free-shipping-for-some-products)

Comment: @GisleHannemyr is it any significant difference? Will question about 1 product not be a dup? About 3? Why should the number of freely shipped products matter at all?

Comment: @GisleHannemyr that's why question merge is for, isn't it? But of course you can vote the other way around, too, and mark older question as a duplicate of this one. Or edit them to make them look different. For now, questions are basically identical, only difference is in answers and answers can be moved around in a merge process so that's not a problem.

Comment: I agree that this question seems better written. Why not close the older one dup of this, and merge them?

Comment: Not sure how the merging works, but i'm happy to look into it if you think this might be a duplicate question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I definitely think you should give [Commerce Discount](https://drupal.org/project/commerce_discount) a try for this, it provides a Free Shipping offer type when commerce shipping is present and thanks to [Inline Conditions](https://drupal.org/project/inline_conditions), you can filter for the products you might want.

Comment: Commerce Discount looks like the best solution for my issue. I was originally hoping to be able to do this without installing additional modules, but Commerce Discount offers solutions for some other features i need to implement as well, so i'll go for this option. Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score -1):

Instead you can try [Commerce Free Shipping](https://drupal.org/project/commerce_free_shipping) module, it will change the price of the service to 0 and can display a message to the user saying the free shipping are applyed or the amount left to obtain free shipping.

> You can use this module to have a free shipping rate by:
>
> - Shipping service
> - Total amount of the line items in the cart (don't take in account the shipping line items)

Comment: Thanks, but this seems to be not quite what i was looking for. I'd like to apply free shipping on a per item bases.